# Python migrations: No handlers could be found for logger "root"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy-migrate

I'm using Python with Flask, and I'm trying to migrate the database. I run `flask db init` and I get `No handlers could be found for logger "root"`. Here is my main script:

```
import os
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import User, Role
from flask_script import Manager

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
app.config.update(dict(
    SECRET_KEY="powerful secretkey",
    WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY="a csrf secret key"
))


@manager.command
def hello():
    print("hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()


@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return dict(db=db, User=User, Role=Role)
```

The server runs ok, but I don't have the database and I should migrate it. 
Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Could be because you may have migration directory already created. Delete it and run again to fix this issue.